# After Upgrade to Buddypress 1.2.6 from 1.2.5.2 , admin bar area displayed incorrectly for guest-visitors

Tags: buddypress

I'm using WP 3.0.1 , and Buddypress 1.2.6 , Theme - Blogs-Mu theme (from WPMU DEV)

I was using BP 1.2.5.2 , and the theme worked fine.

I just upgraded to BP 1.2.6 , and now found a problem ...

Hide admin bar for logged out users? is checked to Yes ...

Now logged out user view a white space at the top (look in the image, a whitespace just below the addressbar) , if the admin bar visibility is turned on for guest visitors the admin bar is displayed instead of the white space ..

http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/4278/whitespaceu.jpg

While using it with BP 1.2.5.2 there was no such white space ?

If any other information is need please gladly ask for it , i will try my level best to provide as much information possible , I just want this issue resolved .

Answer (score 1):

why not contact the company who developed the theme? - they provide support for their customers.
http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/buddypress-blogsmu-theme
http://buddypress.org/community/groups/how-to-and-troubleshooting/forum/topic/what-necessary-changes-should-be-made-to-bp-themes-for-bp-1-2-6/

Maybe the theme was not tested/compatible with bp1.2.6 yet or have issued an update since.